# Why do get this error when trying to lauch MC Failed to download file. minecraftforge-9.11.1.1345.jar?

Tags: java, json, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am currently working for the Crafting Dead as a developer and I need to make an installer for our mod. The installer had to download the latest cd mod from our download server, put the .jar in the mod folder and install forge 1.6.4 + add it in the launcher_profiles.json. I have made the installer in java and it works. When I try to start mc with forge 1.6.4 on windows, it works but it doesn't work on mac.
I get this error:

```
Failed to download file. minecraftforge-9.11.1.1345.jar
Name: minecraftforge-9.11.1.1345.jar
URL: http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/minecraftforge/9.11.1.1345/minecraftforge-9.11.1.1345.jar
Error details: HTTP 404: Not Found
Filename on disk: 17f7-dc92-6e47-f44b
Path: /var/folders/x0/k0n7yhy16214c5wjk2ydj0sh0000gn/T/17f7-dc92-6e47-f44b
Exists: false
```

I had to give the version a custom name. I have called it: CraftingDead so the user knows that that's the version of forge for our mod.

CraftingDead.json(the 1.6.4 version of forge that I have called CraftingDead)

```
{
    "id": "CraftingDead",
    "time": "2018-05-27T02:57:17+0000",
    "releaseTime": "1960-01-01T00:00:00-0700",
    "type": "release",
    "minecraftArguments": "--username ${auth_player_name} --version ${version_name} --gameDir ${game_directory} --assetsDir ${assets_root} --assetIndex ${assets_index_name} --uuid ${auth_uuid} --accessToken ${auth_access_token} --userType ${user_type} --tweakClass net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker --versionType Forge",
    "mainClass": "net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch",
    "inheritsFrom": "1.6.4",
    "jar": "1.6.4",
    "logging": {},
    "libraries": [
        {
            "name": "net.minecraftforge:minecraftforge:9.11.1.1345",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/"
        },
        {
            "name": "net.minecraft:launchwrapper:1.8",
            "serverreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "org.ow2.asm:asm-all:5.2",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/",
            "checksums": [
                "2ea49e08b876bbd33e0a7ce75c8f371d29e1f10a"
            ],
            "serverreq": true,
            "clientreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "jline:jline:2.13",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/",
            "checksums": [
                "2d9530d0a25daffaffda7c35037b046b627bb171"
            ],
            "serverreq": true,
            "clientreq": false
        },
        {
            "name": "com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.3.3",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/",
            "checksums": [
                "ed62e9fc709ca0f2ff1a3220daa8b70a2870078e",
                "25a86ccfdb6f6dfe08971f4825d0a01be83a6f2e"
            ],
            "serverreq": true,
            "clientreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "com.typesafe:config:1.2.1",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/",
            "checksums": [
                "f771f71fdae3df231bcd54d5ca2d57f0bf93f467",
                "7d7bc36df0989d72f2d5d057309675777acc528b"
            ],
            "serverreq": true,
            "clientreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "org.scala-lang:scala-actors-migration_2.11:1.1.0",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/",
            "checksums": [
                "dfa8bc42b181d5b9f1a5dd147f8ae308b893eb6f",
                "8c9aaeeb68487ca519411a14068e1b4d69739207"
            ],
            "serverreq": true,
            "clientreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.11.1",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/",
            "checksums": [
                "56ea2e6c025e0821f28d73ca271218b8dd04926a",
                "1444992390544ba3780867a13ff696a89d7d1639"
            ],
            "serverreq": true,
            "clientreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "org.scala-lang.plugins:scala-continuations-library_2.11:1.0.2",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/",
            "checksums": [
                "87213338cd5a153a7712cb574c0ddd2edfee0386",
                "0b4c1bf8d48993f138d6e10c0c144e50acfff581"
            ],
            "serverreq": true,
            "clientreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "org.scala-lang.plugins:scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1:1.0.2",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/",
            "checksums": [
                "1f7371605d4ba42aa26d3443440c0083c587b4e9",
                "1ea655dda4504ae0a367327e2340cd3beaee6c73"
            ],
            "serverreq": true,
            "clientreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/",
            "checksums": [
                "0e11da23da3eabab9f4777b9220e60d44c1aab6a",
                "1e4df76e835201c6eabd43adca89ab11f225f134"
            ],
            "serverreq": true,
            "clientreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "org.scala-lang:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:1.0.1",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/",
            "checksums": [
                "f05d7345bf5a58924f2837c6c1f4d73a938e1ff0",
                "a1cbbcbde1dcc614f4253ed1aa0b320bc78d8f1d"
            ],
            "serverreq": true,
            "clientreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.1",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/",
            "checksums": [
                "6580347e61cc7f8e802941e7fde40fa83b8badeb",
                "91ce0f0be20f4a536321724b4b3bbc6530ddcd88"
            ],
            "serverreq": true,
            "clientreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "org.scala-lang:scala-swing_2.11:1.0.1",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/",
            "checksums": [
                "b1cdd92bd47b1e1837139c1c53020e86bb9112ae",
                "d77152691dcf5bbdb00529af37aa7d3d887b3e63"
            ],
            "serverreq": true,
            "clientreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "org.scala-lang:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.2",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/",
            "checksums": [
                "7a80ec00aec122fba7cd4e0d4cdd87ff7e4cb6d0",
                "62736b01689d56b6d09a0164b7ef9da2b0b9633d"
            ],
            "serverreq": true,
            "clientreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "lzma:lzma:0.0.1",
            "serverreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:5.0.3",
            "serverreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "java3d:vecmath:1.5.2",
            "clientreq": true,
            "serverreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "net.sf.trove4j:trove4j:3.0.3",
            "clientreq": true,
            "serverreq": true
        },
        {
            "name": "org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:3.5.3",
            "url": "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/",
            "serverreq": true,
            "clientreq": true
        }
    ]
}
```

launcher_profiles.json

```
{
  "settings": {
    "locale": "en-gb",
    "showMenu": false
  },
  "launcherVersion": {
    "name": "2.1.1433",
    "format": 21,
    "profilesFormat": 2
  },
  "clientToken": "23ad82ae7e480408308c753d702a71e6",
  "profiles": {
    "688638ad3da18e808138ba5f9a6f0b9d": {
      "type": "latest-release",
      "lastUsed": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z"
    },
    "ab6e482ee930eac0998c885d4f8bb2d7": {
      "type": "latest-snapshot",
      "lastUsed": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "fcd7ab729dda024a8819b9670bd6e7b7": {
      "name": "",
      "type": "custom",
      "created": "2018-11-03T22:50:44.406Z",
      "lastUsed": "2018-11-03T22:53:23.137Z",
      "lastVersionId": "1.6.4"
    },
    "CraftingDead": {
      "name": "CraftingDead",
      "type": "custom",
      "created": "2018-09-10T15:18:56.115Z",
      "lastUsed": "2018-11-04T21:04:44.020Z",
      "lastVersionId": "CraftingDead"
    },
    "forge": {
      "name": "forge",
      "type": "custom",
      "created": "2018-11-04T20:57:48.500Z",
      "lastUsed": "2018-11-04T20:58:15.835Z",
      "lastVersionId": "1.12.2-forge1.12.2-14.23.4.2705"
    },
    "2cf2d472774625afad6ebf1ad00c2c62": {
      "name": "",
      "type": "custom",
      "created": "2018-11-04T20:58:07.500Z",
      "lastUsed": "2018-11-04T21:01:25.313Z",
      "lastVersionId": "1.12.2-forge1.12.2-14.23.4.2705"
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: If you are refering to MC forge you should probably use the [minecraft-forge] tag instead of the [forge] tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error `Error details: HTTP 404: Not Found` indicates that you are requesting a resource not present on the server. This probably means the URL is wrong, this might also happen if file has been moved, or the file does no longer exist on the server.

Also the day before you asked this question there were reports on the minecraftforge server having problems which might not have been resolved till your request.
You might also want to change the URL's to use https instead of http, as, from what I can tell, it is planed to switch the servers to https only so your request will then fail again.